# Error: SqlException: Invalid object name 'Clients' in Identity Server 4 Project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I would like to connect Identity Server to the Sql Server in my Asp.net core AuthServer project. But I am getting the error in the InitlizeDatabase(app) step as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Does the ConfigurationDbContext you are using have a Clients DbSet?

Answer (score 1):

Check the migration folder to make sure your migration is actually creating the Clients table.

Comment: When I do "Add-Migration first" then comes the "Build Failed" Error. But I can run the project, if the comment out the InitializeDatabase(app) line, without error.

As the migration command is failing, so the migrations did not occur therefor the migrations folder is not created.

Answer (score 0):

It was the EF Core version issue.

When I used the ef and the ef tool version as given in the documentation and it worked :)

So my code works with the version below:
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"